# Primeng datatable is unable to bind the data

Tags: angular

**user-list.page.html**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="userser" [rows]="10" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200px">
<p-column field="USER_NAME" header="USER ID"></p-column>
<p-column field="USER_ID" header="USER NAME" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="DEPT_NAME" header="DEPARTMENT" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="ACTIVE" header="ACTIVE" [sortable]="true"></p-column></p-dataTable>
```

**user-list.page.ts**

```
import User from './services/user';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';
export class Userdetails {
    userser: User[];
    constructor(private userservice: UserService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.userservice.getUsers().subscribe((userser: any) => this.userser = userser);
    }
}
```

**user-list.json**

```
{"userdata":
    {"userlist":[
        {"USER_ID":"SS","USER_NAME":"KUMAR"},
        {"USER_ID":"SUDHEER","USER_NAME":"SS"},
        {"USER_ID":"BHARGAV","USER_NAME":"TEJ"}
    ]}
},
```

**user-service.ts** (a HTTP service to bind the values from the JSON file)

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get('app/assets/user-list.json')
            .map(response => response.json().data as User[]);
    }
}
```